# Missing Dictionaries on Kentico 13

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc

I followed a default process to install kentico 13 ASP.NET CORE locally, selected a new site. Then upgraded to 13.0.5. Everything compiled fine and worked as expected. When I tried to deploy the CMSApp project to azure using visual studio, I got this error.

> Error Copying file App_Data\Dictionaries\en-GB.dic to
> obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\App_Data\Dictionaries\en-GB.dic failed.
> Could not find file 'App_Data\Dictionaries\en-GB.dic'.

Why there are missing dictionaries, I had to pull the missing files from an old Kentico 11 project but, was it something missing during the installation? or could it be a bug?

Is there a way to ignore it?

App_Data-> Dictionaries just had:

- en-US.dic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure by default Kentico Xperience only comes with en-US dictionary included.
This is the default culture.

If you need other cultures (like en-GB) then you need to download them from [here](https://docs.xperience.io/configuring-xperience/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-the-editor-for-rich-text-fields/adding-dictionaries-to-the-rich-text-field-editor-spelling-checker) and include them in your project.

Did you add a reference to `App_Data\Dictionaries\en-GB.dic` yourself?  If you don't need it you could remove it from CMSApp.csproj.

Comment: Yep, Adding the dictionaries manually solved the problem. I don't need it, so, I'll remove those references. Now, thinking about it, I am pretty sure those references were included when importing the site. But no issues were logged until azure deployment tried to pull the missing files. Locally the site compiled fine. Thanks @liamgold